# Suspicious and unknown tables in sql

Tags: sql, wordpress

I was checking my website database when I came across a suspicious table.
In most tables, names like wp_jjj or wp_gooooog can be seen, followed by the names of the plugins used.
The number of this table is also very large. Are these tables destructive and what should be done with them?
I also attached a picture to better understand this issue.
thanks guys
[image: Image of suspicious and unknown tables in sql]

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this isn't a programming question. May be on topic here I don't know https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this may be based on plugins or other things, so to make sure I suggest you check if these tables are used.
You can also use these two plugins to do this:

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-sweep/
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugins-garbage-collector/